# Why can't I use/cast an Action for/to a ThreadStart?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, action

Both are delegates and have the same signature, but I can not use Action as ThreadStart.

Why?

```
Action doIt;
doIt = () => MyMethod("test");
Thread t;

t = new Thread(doIt);
t.Start();
```

but this seems to work:

```
Thread t;

t = new Thread(() => MyMethod("test"));
t.Start();
```

Comment: It looks like theres an implicit cast from a delegate to an Action but not the other way around. You could try to make one or you could just change `t = new Thread(doIt);` to `t = new Thread(doIt.Invoke);` for the same results.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As others have noted, the problem is that delegate types are not "structural". That is, they do not have equivalence based on their "structure".

Now, this is arguably a good thing for some types. If you have

```
struct MyRectangle { int x; int y; int width; int height; ... }
```

and

```
struct YourRectangle { int x1; int y1; int x2; int y2; ... }
```

obviously it would be a mistake to allow instances of MyRectangle to be assigned to variables of YourRectangle, just because they both consisted of four ints. The *semantics* of the ints are different and therefore the types are not equivalent.

The same is, in theory, true of delegates. You could have

```
delegate int Pure(string x);
delegate int Func(string x);
```

where a "pure" function is one with no side effects and the same output given the same input. Since every Pure is logically a Func, but every Func is not necessarily a Pure, there shouldn't be structural typing between them.

In practice of course the type system does not support notions like "pure function" very well. And in practice, the vast majority of attempts to convert between delegate types are perfectly safe: converting from a `Func<int, bool>` to a `Predicate<int>` and so on.

So, two things, one looking backwards and one looking forwards. Backwards: if we had to do it all over again, I think delegates would probably be structurally typed in the CLI.  You don't always know what features are going to be useful when you design a brand new framework, and non-structural delegate types have thus far turned out to be not as useful as perhaps anticipated.  Forwards: I expect to see more features in future versions of the CLR that enable more structural typing. The "no pia" feature in C# 4, for example, is about making two types that are semantically and structurally the same, but defined in different assemblies, logically unify structurally.

Comment: Any chance delegates could become structural, i.o.w. would that break anything?

Comment: Sure, all kinds of things could break. That would be a massive breaking change. *Any* change to the type conversion rules causes a breaking change. If you make what used to be legal illegal, obviously that is a breaking change. If you make something that used to be illegal legal, then you might introduce an ambiguity in overload resolution.

Comment: One could go a long way by simply adding overloads that accept an appropriate variant of `Action`/`Func` to all APIs that take delegates. That’s a *lot* of overloads though... As an extra benefit, the expected signature is immediately obvious via IntelliSense, without any further Visual Studio tweaks.

Comment: Would also be nice if instead of issuing error CS1660 (cannot convert lambda expression to type ...), the compiler assumed an `Action`/`Func` type and proceeded from there. Though this one is also solvable [with a helper method](http://pastebin.com/R35V21RC).

Comment: how about adding a cute little Thread class ctor overload with parameter Action (instead of ThreadStart), that should satisfy a lot of people. PS: how about adding a ctor as an extension method :O, crazy!

Answer (score 5):

The basic form of this error is:

```
delegate void d1();
delegate void d2();
d1 a;
d2 b;
b = a;

Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleDemo1.d1' to 'ConsoleDemo1.d2'
```

---

So you could 'solve' your first sample by using the correct delegate type:

```
//Action doIt;
ThreadStart doIt;
doIt = () => MyMethod("test");
Thread t = new Thread(doIt);
```

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing. I'm seeing an implicit cast from a delegate to an action but no implicit cast from an action to a delegate.

Comment: @Spencer, Action is a (specific) delegate.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this should work?

```
Action doIt;
doIt = () => MyMethod("test");
Thread t;

t = new Thread(doIt.Invoke);
t.Start();
```

Comment: yes this works. BUT! WHY? And why can I call Invoke with out brackets?
Since when C# methods can be invoked in the VB style :D?

Comment: @Rookian: `doIt.Invoke` is automatically wrapped in a `ThreadStart` delegate.  It is not actually invoking `Invoke`.  This is the same behavior you see with any other method that returns void and has no parameters.

Comment: @Rookian: First, I'd imagine there's no implicit cast from Action to a delegate because you'd be casting to a type that carries less data. There's nothing stopping you from writing an implicit cast anyway but the .Net designers must not have felt like it was a good idea to include this standard. Second you're not invoking the function when you don't include the parenthesis, you're passing the method group which has an implicit cast to the ThreadStart delegate.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour your are noticing is because `Action` is a type and the 'lambda' in your second, working example, is not.

Arguably, they are the same, but you are using a concrete framework type when using `Action`, whereas the compiler infers the signature of the lambda.

EDIT: to be clear:

Action is a delegate type, which is `not` a ThreadStart delegate, so while you can assign the lambda expression to both, you cannot use both to start a thread.

In the second example you are giving the compiler the opportunity to infer the type of delegate and, with no great surprise, it is able to assign the lamda expression to the type ThreadStart.

Comment: The lambda shouldn't be a type, it is a value assignable to the Action/ThreadStart types. The lambda is not involved in the error.

Comment: It absolutely is, Henk. In the latter example, the lambda is inferred to be a ThreadStart, while in the former, it is explicitly typed as an Action. The latter is compatible with one of the Thread class constructors, while the former is not.

Comment: @Henk, ? are you agreeing with me or implying that I stated otherwise? not sure....

Comment: No, I was not agreeing with you. As i said, the lambda is not involved, the error is in `new Thread(doIt)`.

Comment: @Henk, So, in that you left the comment on my answer I must infer that you think I said otherwise. Let me be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Delegates with the same signature are not the same in the eyes of the CLR - they are entirely different types.

Answer (score 2):

Because thread start is a separate delegate type and `Action` cannot be converted to `ThreadStart`.

This case works because here your lambda is treated by compiler as ThreadStart:

```
Thread t;

t = new Thread(() => MyMethod("test"));
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the following verbiage in section 26.3.1 of the C# Language Specification is important:

> Similar to an
>   anonymous-method-expression, a
>   lambda-expression is classified as a
>   value with special conversion rules.
>   The value does not have a type but can
>   be implicitly converted to a
>   compatible delegate type.
>   Specifically, a delegate type D is
>   compatible with a lambda-expression L
>   provided: 
>  [List elided]

Which prevents code like this from compiling:

```
var doIt = () => MyMethod("test");    // CS0815
```

Which leads to:

```
Action<object> doIt = (o) => MyMethod("test");
t = new Thread((ParameterizedThreadStart)doIt);  // CS0030
```

Defeated by the compiler disallowing conversions from one delegate type to another, even if their signatures are compatible.  Forcing:

```
ParameterizedThreadStart doIt = (o) => MyMethod("test");
t = new Thread(doIt);
```

Which compiles without trouble.

---

Irrelevant bonus feature: early usability tests on the first Apple Mac discovered a problem with the first version of the OK button on the dialogs that used a sans-serif font.  Users were often clicking Cancel instead, with some visible anguish.  After several interviews, one user finally admitted the problem: "I hate it when a computer calls me a Dolt!"

Well, a compiler calling you a dolt perhaps isn't that irrelevant :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doIt));
```

or

```
t = new Thread( ()=>MyMethod("test"));
```

You're trying to pass an argument of type "Action" to a constructor that takes a ThreadStart. There isn't an implicit conversion defined, so you need to manually invoke the ThreadStart constructor.