# Generic type to hold a delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a method which takes a ThreadStart as a parameter and I usually call it like:

```
public void myMethod(ThreadStart ts) { ... }
myMethod(delegate () {...});
```

I would like to have this delegate assigned to a variable, though, before passing it into the function. When I use

```
Action myDel = delegate () {...};
myMethod(myDel);
```

.. I get an error about no matching method signature. What type can I make `myDel` so that it can be used interchangeably with the actual body of the delegate?

Comment: Forget `ThreadStart`. Use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` or the like. Otherwise if you're in C# 5 use `async / await`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you define your myDel as a ThreadStart delegate like this ??

```
ThreadStart myDel = () => DoSomething();
```

**ThreadStart** and **Action** delegates signatures matching but they are different types. So you can simply define your delegate as a ThreadStart..

Comment: +1. Eric Lippert explains why delegates with the same signature are not compatible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488643/why-cant-i-use-cast-an-action-for-to-a-threadstart

Answer (score 0):

The reason  for this  is you cannot assign a delegate to another delegate(just because two classes have the same fields doesn't mean that you should be able to treat one as if it were another. The same logic applies to delegates)
see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465113/casting-delegate) by Jon Skeet
 *"compatibility" doesn't necessarily meant that the signatures are identical)*

So for example you can use this tricky mode to let your code work

```
        Action myDel = delegate () {};
         myMethod( new ThreadStart(myDel));
```